# Perform business intelligence on google analytics data stored in MongoDB

Tags: business-intelligence, mongodb

I have Google analytics data ( dimensions and metrics) stored in a mongoDB database and I would like to query this data in a MDX style, then display it on the software I am working on. I was wondering if there is a FREE software than performs multidimensional queries on such data and then offers the results via a REST API so they can be consumed with other software.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [MetaBase](http://metabase.com) it has a lot of features, plus it takes only 5-minutes to install and supports a lot of databases.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Elasticsearch or Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products) may be what you are looking for. You can install them for free yourself but they are quite technical. This should not be a problem as you are mentioning MDX style which, in and of itself, is quite an advanced technology.